# How to get the current playback time from moviePlayer?

Tags: iphone, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller, iphone-sdk-3.2

As i know
 `moviePlayer.duration`
can get the duration of a movie, i know

`playableDuration,
initialPlaybackTime,endPlaybackTime`,

but i want to get the current playback time of the moviePlayer .And if there has this method,which Notification should be sent to where,thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MPMoviePlayer adopts the MPMediaPlayback protocol *since 3.2*, which contains [the property `.currentPlaybackTime`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaPlayback_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/MPMediaPlayback/currentPlaybackTime).

Comment: Even it is listen in the Document , it is not working properly. if i set the value to the 50 , it is moving to the 47.9 etc..,